# Add button to put extra in Intent and Remove button to empty all

Tags: android, listview, button, android-intent

I have and Add and Remove button in my listView Adapter class as below. I want to remove everything i add when i click on Add button, by clicking on Remove button. The thing is i tried `getIntent.removeExtra();` but it's not working.

Any ideas?

```
public class CustomRestaurantMenuAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Restaurant> {
private List<Restaurant> items;

public CustomRestaurantMenuAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
}
public CustomRestaurantMenuAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Restaurant> items) {
    super(context, resource, items);
    this.items = items;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.menu_item_list, null);
    }
    Restaurant p = getItem(position);
    if (p != null) {
        TextView foodId = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id._id);
        final TextView foodName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView foodDescription = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.description);
        final TextView foodPrice = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.price);
      final  Button  addButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.addButton);
       final Button  removeButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.removeButton);

        if (foodId != null) {
            foodId.setText("" + p.getId());
        }
        if (foodName != null) {
            foodName.setText("" + p.getName());
        }
        if (foodDescription != null) {
            foodDescription.setText(p.getDescription());
        }
        if (foodPrice != null) {
            foodPrice.setText(p.getPrice());
        }

        removeButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String sName = foodName.getText().toString();
                String sPrice = foodPrice.getText().toString();
                Intent orderDetails = new Intent(getContext(), OrderActivity.class);
                orderDetails.putExtra("name", sName);
                orderDetails.putExtra("price", sPrice);
                Log.d("NAME  ", sName);
                Log.d("PRICE  ", sPrice);
                removeButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        removeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               //remove what is added to intent here or undo the add action
                removeButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });

    }
    return v;
}
 }
```

Comment: Where you are using `getIntent.removeExtra()` ?

Comment: what are you doing with orderDetails intent there is no any startactivity in your code

Comment: I tired to use it in removeButton, but i get "cannot resolve method getIntent()" @ρяσѕρєя K

Comment: post your complete class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of removing all extras one by one, you can reinitialize your intent like that:

```
removeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           // Re-init your intent
            orderDetails = new Intent(getContext(), OrderActivity.class);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just define a class member for your Intent, then just call `yourIntent = new Intent();` when you want to get rid of the extras. This would be the easiest way to do it since you are manipulating your Intent from multiple inner classes.